# jsscrollpane not working on ie9

Tags: jquery, css, html, jscrollpane

i am using jsscrollpane for one of the project. i found it working fine on all the other browsers except **IE9**. i have also tried it using **IE8** and it was working fine there.

this is the test page i have created for that

https://staging-mop-ca-mypack.es-dm.com/Templates/Footer/TermsandConditions.aspx

i am calling the jsscrollpane through this call

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
```

this call is in **main.js** which i am calling on page header.

[image: IE9 overflow]
Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: its working fine in my ie9

Comment: added the image for every one's reference.